# How to use existing bootstrap + jquery templates in VueJS?

Tags: jquery, vue.js

I start to use VueJS to develop an PWA apps, I try to use existing Bootstrap + Jquery Template Called Gentelella Alela!. after manually add all the external script and css, its work fine but somehow my sidebar effect didnt working,

i add the external link in index.html before the  tag, and when i check the console no error and warning is given. is there anything i miss before using existing template or is there any other solution?

Comment: Showing the relevant code or better yet a snippet would be the first step in getting the help you seek.

Comment: You shouldn't mix Vue.js with JQuery.  Perhaps this question is similar to that: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48595148/bootstraps-javascript-requires-jquery-in-vue-2-5/49686885#49686885

Comment: @FabioZanchi That is just not true. There's nothing wrong with mixing Vue and jQuery. Don't mislead people.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy There is nothing wrong it's just not recommended as you can do everything using Vue.js and there's no need to mix both. There's actually an old article about it: https://vuejsdevelopers.com/2017/05/20/vue-js-safely-jquery-plugin/  ;)